# Javamail and adding link to text

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using Javamail. Within the MimeMessage.setText, I have to include code that encodes text as a URL. For the purposes like below.

`BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();`

```
messageBodyPart.setText("Test\n" + text +"\nVisit Test.com");`
```

In this I need Test.com to be embedded as a URL. Is there a tag or wildcard that would do this? Thanks.

Basically I would prefer to avoid using html in the javamail and utilizing the following.

Test.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the link to be clickable in the mail, you should send the mail as HTML.

To do this, you should try to create an HTML MIME mail:

```
InternetHeaders headers = new InternetHeaders();
headers.addHeader("Content-type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
String html = "Test\n" + text + "\n<a href='http://test.com'>Test.com</a>";
MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart(headers, html.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

EDIT:

It is also possible to use setText when sending HTML-mail:

```
String html = "Test\n" + text + "\n<a href='http://test.com'>Test.com</a>";
messageBodyPart.setText(html, "UTF-8", "html");
```

See the [the API for more details](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things need to happen for this to work.

1. Send the link as html
2. Set the content type to `text/html`

`String text = "Test\n" + text +"\nVisit <a href="http://test.com">Test.com</a>";
messageBodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html");`

From [JavaMail API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#sendhtml)

> **Q: How do I send HTML mail?**
>   A: There are a number of demo programs included with the distribution that show how to send HTML mail. If you want to send a simple message that has HTML instead of plain text, see the **sendhtml.java** program in the demo directory. If you want to send an HTML file as an attachment, see the **sendfile.java** example that shows how to send any file as an attachment.